# Hyperbolic Trigonometry with Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I was trying to show the following complex hyperbolic trigeometric relation

$$\mathrm{arctanh}(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arctanh}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)+\frac{i}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2y}{1-x^2-y^2}\right),$$

where $x,y$ are real numbers. The formula helps to separate the real and imaginary parts of the hyperbolic trigeometric function of a complex argument $z=x+iy$. I know it is correct because wolfram alpha gives practically numerical zero. I thought of making use of the relations such as $$\mathrm{tanh}(iy)=i \tan(y),$$ and $$\mathrm{tanh}(x+y)=\frac{\mathrm{tanh}(x)+\mathrm{tanh}(y)}{1+\mathrm{tanh}(x)\mathrm{tanh}(y)}.$$ In fact I tried to multiply 2 on both sides of the expression and then evaluate the $\mathrm{tanh}$ of them, and I end up in the following expression 
$$\frac{2 x + i 2 y}{1 + x^2 - y^2 + (2 i) (x y)} - \frac{ 2x/(1 + x^2 + y^2) + i 2 y/(1 - x^2 - y^2)}{1 + ( 2x/(1 + x^2 + y^2))  ( i2y/(1 - x^2 - y^2))}$$
which gives zero. Is there a straightforward way to show the validity of the above formula?

*Edit: As pointed out by user5713492, there was a algebraic mistake in the original question*

Comment: hint: maybe you need to use $u = \tanh^{-1}(z)$, and look at $\bar{u} + u$, and study the conjugates.

Comment: Many thanks! By calculating $u+\bar{u}$, one obtains the real part of $u=\mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(z)$, and by making use of $\mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+z}{1-z}$. I got the desired answer. But why the straightforward substitution does not get me the right answer? Is there a simple algebraic mistake?

Comment: Your algebraic mistake: you should have $$\frac{2x+i2y}{1+x^2-y^2+(2i)(xy)}$$

Comment: thx! I really should have taken more care.

Comment: "Trigeometry": interesting neologism !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is based on Kf-Sansoo's hint. It is noted that $$\mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+z}{1-z},$$ which can be obtained by reverting $$z \equiv \mathrm{tanh}(w)=\frac{e^{2w}-1}{e^{2w}+1}.$$
Then, one can calculate $u+\bar{u}$ to obtain the real part of $u=\mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(z)$. Explicit calculations give $$2\mathbf{Re}(u)=u+\bar{u}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+z}{1-z}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}}{1-\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}}=\mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}).$$ Similarly, one has $$2\mathbf{Im}(u)=u-\bar{u}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+z}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+\bar{z}}{1-\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1+\frac{i2y}{1-x^2-y^2}}{1-\frac{i2y}{1-x^2-y^2}}=i\mathrm{tan}^{-1}(\frac{2y}{1-x^2-y^2}).$$ This yields the desired result.